# Including a space in set /p inputs automatically crash the batch program

Tags: batch-file

I am very much a newb at batch programming, but I can't seem to find an answer that fixes my problem. Any time I include a `set /p` command into my batch file, inputting anything that includes a space between letters instantly closes the program. 
Here's the code in question:

```
set /p action=">>"
if not defined action goto nothing
if /i %action% equ fight goto fight
if /i %action% equ magic goto magic
if /i %action% equ heal goto heal
if /i %action% equ "do nothing" goto nothing
goto battscr
```

I'm obviously trying to create a response to the input, "do nothing", but every time a user types a space between characters, immediately after pressing enter it will close. Running the batch through cmd gives the error "nothing was unexpected at this time." with "nothing" referring to the input after the space.

Comment: The answer is printed right to your screen: After "nothing was unexpected at this time" you see `if /i do nothing equ fight goto fight`. Notice that this does follow the allowable syntax `if /i string1 equ string2 ...`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand your answer. The variable is %action%. `if /i do nothing equ fight goto fight` acts as if "do nothing" is the variable, when I want that to be the input which the variable is equal to. Also, when the batch is run in cmd and the error "nothing was unexpected at this time" appears, it immediately closes the bat and jumps to my C: directory. Nothing happens relating to the bat afterwards.

Comment: As noted the syntax is `if /i string1 equ string2` - only one string before the `equ` but you are putting two. The parser expects the second word after the `/i` to be `equ` but instead it is `nothing`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that it would run through each variable before it reaches that last one. I fixed it by placing parentheses around each variable so that it sees it as 1 string. Fixed Code:                                                    
 `set /p action=">>"
if not defined action goto nothing
if /i "%action%" equ fight goto fight
if /i "%action%" equ magic goto magic
if /i "%action%" equ heal goto heal
if /i "%action%"=="do nothing" goto nothing
goto battscr`

Comment: You should consider reading the help for a command before you ask a question about it.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`

Comment: I did that and I read through the entire thing, but I was set on the idea that the problem was with my set /p syntax. I just assumed that it would move on if the syntax didn't work with the if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either this syntax:

```
IF /I "%VARIABLE%" EQU "STRING" GOTO LABEL
```

Or preferably this:

```
IF /I "%VARIABLE%"=="STRING" GOTO LABEL
```

*The double quotes are included in the comparison.*